# Creating a range relative to a booelan index using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

What's a good way to select a range based on the reference point of a boolean index?

For example, suppose I have the following dataframe, df:

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.empty([10, 3]), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B','C'])
df.iloc[:3,0] = 100
df.iloc[3:7,0] = 200
df.iloc[7:,0] = 300
df.iloc[:5,1] = 400
df.iloc[5:,1] = 500
df.iloc[:7,2] = 600
df.iloc[7:,2] = 700
```

and the boolean dataframe:

```
df1 = [df!=df.shift(1)]
```

I would like to populate a range of 3 cells prior where the booleans are True.

Is there not a single-line method to get a boolean range relative to a reference?  The result would look something like this:

```
                A      B      C
2000-01-01  False  False  False
2000-01-02   True  False  False
2000-01-03   True  False  False
2000-01-04   True   True  False
2000-01-05  False   True  False
2000-01-06   True   True   True
2000-01-07   True  False   True
2000-01-08   True  False   True
2000-01-09  False  False  False
2000-01-10  False  False  False
```

Comment: What happenes to column C? And also can you explain more on *3 cells a change in the time series*?

Comment: I believe I've addressed your questions via my recent edits.  Let me know if anything remains unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the `bfill` (backward fill) method with a limit parameter:

```
df.shift().where(df.diff() != 0, pd.np.nan).bfill(limit=2).fillna(0).astype(bool)
```

[image]